# /conf directory missing error in Hadoop 2.5.1

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, ubuntu-14.04

I have configured the Hadoop 2.5.1 on my system. When I am trying to start the nodes, I am getting the error: 'Cannot find configuration directory: /conf' as shown below.

```
hduser@System-Vaio:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh
Incorrect configuration: namenode address dfs.namenode.servicerpc-address or 
dfs.namenode.rpc-address is not configured.
Starting namenodes on []
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /conf
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /conf
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
Error: Cannot find configuration directory: /conf
hduser@System-Vaio:/usr/local/hadoop/sbin$ jps
5482 Jps
```

What could be the reason behind this error? I have followed this [link](http://bigdatahandler.com/2013/11/02/installing-single-node-hadoop-2-2-0-on-ubuntu/) for the installation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that HADOOP_CONF_DIR is invalid , try to set correct path in **.bashrc** file.
After editing the .bashrc file, compile it by using the command **source ~/.bashrc**

Answer (score 1):

HADOOP_CONF_DIR seems to be missing in `.bashrc` file.

Make sure that `bashrc` look like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path>/jdk1.7.0_71
export HADOOP_INSTALL=<path>/hadoop-2.5.1
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_INSTALL/sbin
export HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_HDFS_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export YARN_HOME=$HADOOP_INSTALL
export HADOOP_COMMON_LIB_NATIVE_DIR=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib/native
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_INSTALL/lib"
```

after all this run the `bash` file by using command `$source .bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your home/hadoopuser/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh file
2. change your CONFIG_DIR to the specific location for bin.
3. restart the system
4. it works like charm

Answer (score 0):

Please, check if the hduser has the total permission of your hadool folder. Indeed, it does not, you will be able to start your cluster.

So, can you tell me how you extract the hadoop tar file?

Answer (score 0):

Set correctly your paths. In your hadoop-env.sh change

`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=$HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/`

to

`export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/`

Also check below.

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

add:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=\${HADOOP_HOME}/etc/hadoop
```

Then:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```